# Terminal Server lags When users logs on?

Tags: windows, terminal-server

First I have to say that my knowledge about Windows Terminals Server is very limited.

At my friend's job they have a terminal server with maximum 11 users. They also have one computer for the AD and Domain controller.

The problem is that every morning when everybody logs on it gets really slow and some user measured the log on time to about 15 minutes.

Can anyone tell me where to start looking? Can I see the memory use or cpu usage per user somewhere?

Also, can I see the load on the network?

Comment: Discuss your problem with the system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at the load performance of the TS server. Pulling up the "Performance" tab on the "Task Manager" is a quick and dirty start. Good chance it may be the CPU being under-power and getting slammed when folks are simultaneously logging on and starting applications across each session.

Was there any period of time in the past where the system support the same number of users without the difficulties? If so, when may the performance issues appeared?

Network utilization is less likely as each RDP session is typically under 100 kbps between the RDP client and the TS server, unless there are network intensive application being run under the actual sessions.

Memory utilization under the same "Performance" tab is also another area to look into.

Comment: Yepp, we looked at the processor load and its totally jammed when everybody logging on.. So, do you think there some specifik application using all CPU power or is it just to slow.. The thng is that that it worked fine before and they haven't added any new applications that i know of.. Can i see which applications that uses all the cpu power? best regards

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771218%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add what @user48838 said, I've also seen Anti Virus do things similar to this, try disabling it to see if it works better. I've also seen GPO have this affect on it as well.